# change image path for upload control dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working in ASP.NET and C#.

I have an `Fileupload` control in my application. I want to change the storage path (on the hard disk) of the image during the upload. How do I go about it.

C# code:

```
     string filename = Path.GetFileName(fileuploadimages.PostedFile.FileName);
    //Save images into Images folder
    fileuploadimages.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("**~/database/**" + filename));
    //Getting dbconnection from web.config connectionstring
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ToString());
    //Open the database connection
    con.Open();
    //Query to insert images path and name into database
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into tblImageupload1(Imagename,Imagepath) values(@ImageName,@ImagePath)", con);
    //Passing parameters to query
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Imagename", filename);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Imagepath", "../Database/" + filename);
    //cmd.Parameters.Add("@price");
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //Close dbconnection
    con.Close();
```

**Note**: I want to change the path `~/database/` dynamically during upload.

Comment: Do you mean while the upload is happening or per upload?

Comment: While i am Uploading i need change.Because I have separate folders for different types of images.

Comment: And how do you detect the type of the image currently?

Comment: its not clear what you want to accomplish

Comment: I have different folders for different types of images in my application,so i want to change the path  ~/database/ which is static for all images dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say "While i am Uploading i need change.Because I have separate folders for different types of images", so you probably have a way to detect the type of the image. Let's assume that you have detected the type of the currently uploaded image and stored it in the variable `imagetype`.

```
string imagetype = ""; // type of image is here, i.e. "Bird", "Forest", "Mountain"

string imagepath = "/images";
switch (imagetype)
{
  case "Bird": imagepath = "/ImagesOfBirds"; break;
  case "Forest": imagepath = "/ImagesOfForests"; break;
  case "Mountain": imagepath = "/ImagesOfMountains"; break;
}

string path = Path.Combine(imagepath, filename);
fileuploadimages.SaveAs(path);
```

Comment: type of images is not the extension,its like animals,birds ect.

Comment: I never said it is an extension. How does the user tell you what type of image it is that they are uploading? Is there perhaps a list of which they select it? Or perhaps a textbox in which they provide the type? How do you know serverside what the type of the image is?